# UIColor vs IB color (color profile issue)

Tags: ios, colors, interface-builder, xcode8, uicolor

I'm using XCode 8.2.1.
I just learned about color profiles and that RGB values are not universal.
But still can't understand how to make it right in code.
In Interface Builder I selected predefined "Dark Gray Color" for a label. It is (85, 85, 85) in Generic RGB profile. Also in code I set another label color to [UIColor darkGrayColor]. I expected them to have the same color, but they are different.

I used method

```
- (BOOL)getRed:(nullable CGFloat *)red green:(nullable CGFloat *)green blue:(nullable CGFloat *)blue alpha:(nullable CGFloat *)alpha
```

to get RGB values. For the label which color was set in IB I see that values are actually (104,104,104) which correspond to values in IB when I switch to Device RGB profile.
So it seems that in code Device RGB profile is used.

So my questions are:

1. Why standard "Dark Gray Color" is different when set in IB and in code?
2. How to use Generic RGB profile in code, so I can match color values with Interface Builder?

Comment: hey @jesse i have just answer below.

Answer (score 14):

Hello Jesse please see answer below:

- **`Why standard "Dark Gray Color" is different when set in IB and in code?`**

Standard `Dark Gray Color` is different using `Storyboard` and programmatically because `Storyboard` uses `sRGB IEC61966-2.1` or `Generic RGB` `Color Profile` by default and when you set it programmatically so it takes `Device RGB` `Color profile` because Device RGB iOS devices out there `iPhones, iPads` have different characteristics in terms of their display color profiles .

- **`How to use Generic RGB profile in code, so I can match color values with Interface Builder?`**

When you set `UIColor` programmatically so you have no choice to select any `Color Profile` because it will take `Device RGB` `Color Profile`.

If you want to make it same, So in your storyboard select your Colour picker, Open settings and change it to `Device RGB`

**See below screen shot for Color Profile Setting using Storyboard**:

[image]

I hope it will help you....

Comment: Perfect answer!!

Comment: Thank @MohamedHaseel :)